# Why no resistor is connected in open collector TTL logic?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, ttl

What will happen if we connect it internally in IC itself?
Why do we need to manually connect it outside?
Is there any advantage of doing so?

Comment: If there was a resistor inside it would not be an open collector.

Comment: Two open collector NPN outputs sharing the same pull-up resistor make another functional gate - either output being low makes a low, both outputs being "high" makes a high - that's an AND gate.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any advantage of doing so?

The wired-AND gate: -

[image]

You can also make a wired-OR gate.

In many situations you can switch a load that has a higher voltage level than the standard 5V for TTL: -

[image]

Here's an example of a TTL logic level amplifier: -

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that, for the higher voltage translation usage, it only works with parts specifically designed for that (e.g., indeed, SN7407), but if you do that with some random part (e.g. 74HC3G07), you'll just burn the chip, exceeding the absolute rating for output voltage.

Answer (score 2):

It's historical, resistive pullup can be very slow and power hungry where buses must be driven. TTL logic replaced RTL (where it was resistive pullups to high in the chip). In the first computers using TTL 7400 logic, most buses (in the 70-120 Ohm range) had external terminations (resistor to VCC and resistor to ground) and the bus drivers were OC. The TTL chips themselves were not able to drive stable high's with large fanout and there were no tri-state chips available. 
Eventually tri-stateable logic made bus design much easier.

So there were multiple reasons open collector outputs were popular in the original 7400 series logic.

It allowed wide Wired 'OR' functions to be easily created (eg. functions using buses).

It allowed high voltage drive (15-30V OC outputs) and higher sink currents (40-60mA) with minimal change to the chip design and retaining the +5V VCC.

It was useful for driving direct I/O functions such as multiplexed displays.

Answer (score 0):

When driving any number of open-collector outputs are combined and used to feed any number of inputs, there should generally only be one pull-up resistor.  Having ten identical outputs, ten identical inputs, and one pull-up resistor, will generally be more convenient than either having one output that has a pull-up and nine that don't, or having one input that has a pull-up and nine that don't.